# Java Base64 decode to image gives null

Tags: java, base64, tiff

I have this code which runs fine and decodes base64 string to images fine except for one image. Below is the code:

```
 byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
    String path = "C:\\Test\\test.tiff";
    File file = new File(path);
    try  {
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        outputStream.write(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried with `Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)` as well but still same error in the image saying 'Windows Photo Viewer cannot display this picture because it is empty'.  However when I take that base64 and run it through online decoders like https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image it decodes correctly to an image. What am I missing?

Comment: *public void close()
           throws IOException

Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

The close method of FilterOutputStream calls its flush method, and then calls the close method of its underlying output stream.* ?

Comment: It would help to post the actual string in a Github gist or additional debugging information.

Comment: Agree with @ScaryWombat, but I suggest using try-with-resource (ie.: `try (OutputStream outputStream ...) {...}`) instead, as that automatically closes the stream in a `finally` block. Side note: As you are writing a single byte array to the output stream, there is no benefit from using `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: Adding  ` outputStream.flush(); outputStream.close();`  inside the finally block fixed this issue. Thanks. I also tried the try-with-resource which also worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

try:

byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
print(data.length()); //